# How to remember which expansion ${var%} ${var#} work from which end?

Tags: bash, shell, parameter-expansion

I am having trouble remembering which one of the parameter expansions `${var%subst}` or `${var#subst}` remove from the front and which one from the back of the string. Example:

```
$ var=/a/b/c
$ echo dirname=${var#/*} filename=${var%%*/}
dirname=a/b/c filename=/a/b/c                      # Wrong!
$ echo dirname=${var%/*} filename=${var##*/}
dirname=/a/b filename=c
```

I always mix them and either end up writing some test commands or checking the manual. It's easy to remember that `%%` removes more then `%`, because `%%` is a longer string then `%`, 2 characters vs 1 character, same for `##` vs `#`. But I always mix `%` with `#`.

Is there a memory rule to know which `%` or `#` remove from which end of the string?

Comment: I just always try one, and if it fails, then the other :P

Comment: consider a cheat sheet of examples; could be a `*.txt` file you can quickly double-click from the desktop, or perhaps define an alias to `cat` the cheat sheet at the command prompt; if you end up with a lot of cheat sheets consider a shell script that runs an input arg through a `case` statement to determine which cheat sheet to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a figurative representation of the symbols:

- `%`: Looks like a pair of scissors to cut the right part of a text strip while you hold the scissors in your right hand and the strip in your left hand.
- `#`: Looks like an eraser you use to erase the left part of a text strip while you hold the right part with your right hand and the eraser in your left hand.
- `//`: This bash specific text-replace, looks like the cuts in a strip to re-assemble or edit in-between parts.

Comment: Thank You! `%: Looks like a pair of scissors to cut the right part of a text strip` This, worked for me, it just "clicked", because scissors are so visual, I imagined that once, and now I always think of scissors when writing scripts. Then I remember that `#` is the opposite of `%`, and I have it.

Answer (score 13):

Percent symbols `%` always come last in numbers (e.g. `86%`), so they remove from the end.

The hash symbols `#` start comments, so they remove from the start.

Comment: "The #1 rule, useful 100% of the time" - That's the phrase I use. Hence `#` removes from the start because it's at the start, `%` removes from the end for the opposite reason. Then the only complication is greedy/non-greedy mode. Obviously people who want *more* (such as `##` rather than `#`) are greedy.

Answer (score 8):

Remember only 1 and other will be Opposite of it.

`#` Shebang starts from a hash which means it will remove from starting till pattern, if you remember this and you know what other does IMHO :)

Answer (score 6):

For keyboards of US English [layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout), `#` is on the left and `%` on the right.

Comment: On **American** keyboards at least. On mine, % is on the left and # is on the right.

Answer (score 0):

And I thought I was alone with this problem.

My mnemonic is that since percent sign (`%`) looks like a slash surrounded by a couple of circles (`°/o`), *put the slashes alongside* ie. `%/` - also, that also looks like it says *o lol* (`°/o/`).

With the asterisk in place (`°/o/*`) it also looks like a <s>guy</s>person holding an orb and a *BZZRT* in <s>his</s>hir raised hands (can not be unseen).