# Use awk in git alias: alias to delete remote branch by full local ref name `git push -d remotes/remote-name/topic/branch`

Tags: git, git-alias

**Why do I want `git push -d remotes/remote-name/topic/branch`?**
It's the format that you get in gitk, often I find remote branches in gitk that I want to delete. Right click the branch name in gitk, copy and do something like `git nuke remotes/remote-name/topic/branch`.

**What I currently have:**
`echo remotes/origin/epic/T-12345 | awk '{gsub(/^remotes\/[^\/]*\//, "")}{print}'`
This works fine, prints `epic/T-12345` - it chops the optional beginning of string `^remotes/.*?/` in terms of PCREs which are easier to read.

**Problem:**
When I try to use it in a git alias like so (git-for-windows, running from git-bash):

```sh
test1 = "!f() { \
  echo ${1} | awk '{gsub(/^remotes\/[^\/]*\//, "")}{print}'; \
}; f"
```

I get `fatal: bad config line 5 in file C:/Users/username/.gitmorealiases`

**The plan was** to do something like:

```sh
test1 = "!f() { \
  REPLACED=`echo ${1} | awk '{gsub(/^remotes\/[^\/]*\//, "")}{print}'`; \
  git push -d origin $REPLACED;
}; f"
```

---

### Two working git aliases from the accepted answer:

Replace `echo` with the actual command you need, e.g. `git push -d origin`

- **Using awk** as originally asked for (can be useful in many situations):

```sh
v1_awk = "!f() { \
  replaced=$(echo "$1" | awk '{gsub(/^remotes\\/[^\\/]*\\//, \"\")}{print}'); \
  echo "$replaced"; \
}; f"
```

- **Using shell** string substitutions (for those who can remember how it works):

```sh
v2_shell = "!f() { echo \"${1#remotes/*/}\"; }; f"
```

Comment: Remove \ and remove newlines. Do one line. Also, check your scripts with shellcheck - do not use backticks.

Comment: @KamilCuk `test3 = "!f() { echo ${1} | awk '{gsub(/^remotes\/[^\/]*\//, "")}{print}'; }; f"` same output: `bad config line...`

Comment: How will shellcheck help? `echo remotes/origin/epic/T-12345 | awk '{gsub(/^remotes\/[^\/]*\//, "")}{print}'` works just fine by itself. Same thing copied into a git alias function does not work.

Comment: I would consider `!f() { ... }; f` a pure anti-pattern from the scalability, maintainability and even sanity points of view. Simply create a `+x` script named `git-any-name-here` (note a dash after the word `git`), put it in your PATH, and then invoke it using `git any-name-here [args...]` (note a space after `git`). I'm almost sure it would also work under Windows + git bash. Also, no need to change Git configuration at all + it your favorite text editors don't need to be aware of the Git config escaping rules therefore providing full edit support for those scripts.

Comment: @fluffy With that instead of just one git-aliases file (which I copy between environments) I need: 1) multiple files 2) all are separate shell commands, they're not recognized as git sub-commands like aliases are. No scalability needed, I don't write big programs in git aliases, just want a way to sanitize input a bit.

Comment: @DmitryAvtonomov It does not really matter because you really faced with a core issue of escaping a script language in a git config having \/\/\/\/\/-like stuff + losing a lot of benefits because of that. When I said "sanity point of view", I meant what I meant: escaping shell scripts in aliases is madness (what if your script gets bigger in the future? what if you don't need to share all your config file (+ not only the alias section) but a part of it only? isn't copying two files instead of a single file worth it? etc-etc-etc). Well, I wish I could never maintain stuff like that.

Comment: @fluffy Ok, point taken. Nevertheless, the question was about doing it from a git alias file. Another thing you loose with your solution is git autocompletion in shell (like branch names etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\/` is an unknown escape sequence, you have to escape `\` inside `"`.

```
test1 = "!f() { replaced=$(echo "$1" | awk '{gsub(/^remotes\\/[^\\/]*\\//, \"\")}{print}') && git push -d origin \"$replaced\"; }; f"
```

From `man git config`: `Inside double quotes, double quote " and backslash \ characters must be escaped: use \" for " and \\ for \.`

As for shell: prefer to use lower case for local variable names, quote variable expansions to prevent word splitting, prefer to use `$(...)` instead of backticks.

Anyway, I think just:

```
test1 = "!f() { git push -d origin \"${1#remotes/*/}\"; }; f"
```

Comment: thank you, your edit of my original command worked. However your suggestion (which I guess uses string replacement baked into shell?) didn't work for me. I tried `test1 = "!f() { echo "${1#remotes/*/}"; }; f"` and it produces: `f() { echo ${1: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `}'`

Comment: Lol, that sounds like `#` is getting parsed as a comment.. Och right, `"` should be `\"`...

Comment: Ok, so that works: `test6 = "!f() { echo \"${1#remotes/*/}\"; }; f"`. I find bash string manipulation very hard to remember.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66421468/how-to-remember-which-expansion-var-var-work-from-which-end :D