# Ensuring a single colon at start of string

Tags: bash, getopts

I am using getopts to parse options.  I want to ensure that the `optstring` has only a single colon at the start, and if this does not exist I want to introduce it.

Here is an example of the initialisation of optstring

```
  local optstring="sn:z:"
```

Comment: There are two parts to the obvious answer, and I suspect they both are already asked and answered elsewhere on this site: Checking whether a string starts with a given prefix, and adding a prefix to a string. Which of those, if either, do you already know how to do?

Comment: (We expect a question to describe not just a goal, but also exactly how you got stuck in your own effort towards that goal).

Comment: Why do you need to do this? You're presumably writing the code to initialize `optstring` so why do you need to write other code to check your code? Please [edit] your code to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the actual problem you're trying to solve as this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: please update the question with the code you've attempted, the (wrong) result generated by your code, and the (correct) expected result

Comment: oddly related https://stackoverflow.com/q/76189223/9072753

Comment: @KamilCuk not oddly - Veak and Bennings are 2 of the **many** logins used by the same person here and on SE.

Comment: I want the `optstring` to change at runtime to go to silent error reporting if the user pass the option `-s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
optstring=:${optstring#:}
```

First we unconditionally add a colon, then we use a parameter expansion to expand our string with any preexisting colon removed.

Comment: This, however, assumes `optstring` starts with at most one `:`.

Comment: @chepner, indeed. One could `shopt -s extglob` and then use `${opstring#+(:)}` to avoid that limitation.

Comment: Is it good to enable `extglob` in the `.bashrc` ?  I have made a library, would the command go into each file individually.  Ideally I would like to always allow it.  Could there be any conflicts that could break other things ?

Comment: @Bennings, technically setting extglob causes pattern-match behavior to break the standard -- that's why it's off-by-default -- but the behaviors that it changes are ones that a person is unlikely to ever actually want. There are certainly some Linux distros that _do_ enable it by default, so you wouldn't be the first to decide it's more benefit than cost.

Comment: By standard, you mean the POSIX Standard ?  You are then claiming of  behaviors performed by  `extglob`  that people do not want ?  Is that because much of the existing system code assumes adherence to POSIX, which would break the behavior when  `extglob` is enabled across the board ?

Comment: @Bennings, I did not, and do not, claim that extglob does things that people don't want in practice. I _do_ assert that it makes the shell's globbing no longer POSIX-compliant. And it's certainly not true that "much of" system code/tools are incompatible with extglob behavior -- little if any is, but if someone wants a _firm guarantee_ that scripts written assuming POSIX behavior will still conform to the letter of the standard (even if only in circumstances that are extremely unlikely to ever happen in real-world practice), then they need extglob off.

Answer (score 1):

This POSIX-compatible code (tested with Bash and Dash) handles arbitrary numbers of colons at the start of the string:

```
optstring=:${optstring#${optstring%%[!:]*}}
```

- `${optstring%%[!:]*}` expands to the (possibly empty) string of colons at the start of `$optstring`.  It does this by removing the first non-colon character (`[!:]`) and everything that follows it.
- `${optstring#${optstring%%[!:]*}}` expands to `$optstring` with all the colons at the start removed.

The transformation can be done in two steps to (possibly) make it more readable:

```
colons=${optstring%%[!:]*}
optstring=:${optstring#$colons}
```

Another (also POSIX-compatible) approach is to use a loop to remove leading colons:

```
while [ "${optstring#:}" != "$optstring" ]; do
    optstring=${optstring#:}
done
optstring=:$optstring
```

Comment: Whilst this expression is effective, it is hard to read and understand, and would need some hard concentration.