# Bash regex group to keep only a single colon at the start of a string

Tags: bash

I am using sed to keep only a single colon at the start of a string.

```
string=$( printf "%s\n" "$string" | sed 's/^::*/:/' )
```

Could this be done in bash using something like

```
[[ $string =~ regex ]]
```

with a regex group that will contain the parts of the string as required ?

Comment: It can be done with Bash extended globbing: `shopt -s extglob; string=${string/#+(:)/:}`.  See the [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) section in [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).

Comment: I know about that one, the extended globbing.  Would it be possible to enable it inside a bash function only.  There has been a discussion recently about whether to allow extended globbing across a bash library.  But the difficulty is that some need extglob off If they wish a firm guarantee that scripts written assuming POSIX behavior will still conform to the standard.  What do you think ?

Comment: Enable the glob inside the function?

Comment: @Jetchisel extglob should have a global scope due to the way bash evaluates blocks

Comment: With bash regex, how about `[[ $string =~ ^:+(.*) ]] && string=":${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"`?

Comment: @SirAthos. Ok, and if you disable `extglob` at the end of the function?

Comment: `regex='^(:{1,})(.*)$';string=:::::::::string:; [[ "$string" =~ $regex ]]; declare -p BASH_REMATCH`

Comment: @Jetchisel I think the requirement here is rather, as a library, not to touch the extglob setting at all.

Comment: Well POSIX, is all about external tools, so yeah, `sed` or `awk` .

Comment: That question was asked before by the same user: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76194470/ensuring-a-single-colon-at-start-of-string

Comment: Yes, a similar question was asked before but this starts with the sed example and mentions that extended globbing could not be suitable for some users.

Comment: There should be no problem having `extglob` enabled globally.   It's very unlikely to cause problems for code that doesn't use extended globbing.  Bash can be built with `extglob` enabled by default, and I've worked on Linux distros where the standard Bash installation had been built in that way.  See [Is it dangerous to always have extglob on?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276911/264812).

Comment: It makes sense for a *library* function that depends on extended globbing to turn on `extglob` and turn it off again if necessary.  One way to do that is `local is_changed_extglob=1; shopt -q extglob && is_changed_extglob=0 || shopt -s extglob; ...; (( is_changed_extglob )) && shopt -u extglob`.

Answer (score 0):

With any posix shell:

```
# ensure exactly one colon
string=:${string#${string%%[!:]*}}

# ensure no more than one colon
case $string in :*) string=:${string#${string%%[!:]*}};; esac
```

Using `BASH_REMATCH`:

```
# ensure exactly one colon
[[ $string =~ ^:*(.*)$ ]]
string=:${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

# ensure no more than one colon
[[ $string =~ ^(:?):*(.*)$ ]]
string=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
```

Comment: I had not noticed before answering that this was a duplicate question with the same posix part of the answer already at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76195107/10971581